# What are Clustering techniques for this case?

Tags: clustering, model-based-clustering

What type of clustering methods are available for ordinal, nominal and ratio variables? Suppose I have one ordinal, one nominal and one ratio variable; is there a common clustering technique that can be applied on the data set?

By creating dummy variables for nominal and ordinal, can I use K-means? If not, why? What are the limitations associated with it?

Comment: If you have different type of features, consider using Gower similarity coefficient (search this site, to read more). Hierarchical clustering, medoid method and some other allow for using arbitrary distances, including Gower coefficient. And no, you may not use k-means with ordinal or nominal data (again, read on this site about k-means).

Comment: You asked the **same question** on SO before. Why didn't you consider the comments there to **improve your question** before reposting? This annoys people that could help you, if you ignore their answer... In particular, I pointed out that the question already exists, and you should **use search**.

Answer (score 2):

The *clustering* algorithm as such usually does not care any more whether your original data were nominal, ordinal or anything else. Instead, most common clustering algorithms only look at *distances* between data points.

Why? Because clustering attempts to group data points into groups such that all data points within a group are "similar", while data points in different groups are "dissimilar". And similarity can be operationalized via distances. If we have a notion of distance between data points, we can say that two data points are similar if the distance between them is small, and that they are dissimilar if the distance is large. In the end, talking about (dis)similarity and distances amounts to the same thing, but it is more common to discuss clustering in terms of distances.

So it seems like your key question is not so much the *clustering* algorithm, but defining the *distance* or (dis)similarity between your data points. Specifically:

- For ordinal variables, you will need to decide whether, e.g., the distance between A and C is double the one between A and B... or the sum of the distances between A and B and between B and C. Or the distance between A and C could be more than either. Or less.
- For nominal variables, the simplest approach usually is dummy coding, which translates into a distance of one between instances that differ on the variable. If you have additional structure on your nominals (perhaps some values are "more different" than others), you can include this.
- Distances between (one-dimensional) ratio variables are usually taken to be the absolute value of the difference, but of course you can do log or power transformations to emphasize small or large absolute differences.

Next, now that you have defined distances between variables, you need to combine them into distances between data points (i.e., collections of variables). Here, you may need to scale stuff to make different dimensions comparable. You can group variables and combine them using the Manhattan, Euclidean, ... distance.

Finally, you toss your distances into k-means or DBSCAN or whatever else.

Comment: `you toss your distances into k-means`. Stephan, what then will be your stance over that many of statements already done on this site, that k-means is appropriate only for Euclidean metric?

Comment: `The clustering algorithm as such usually does not care any more whether your original data were nominal, ordinal or anything else`. So, it means that all contemporary clustering methods are totally independent of the notion of the type distance to use. I feel that this statement is historically premature.

Comment: @ttnphns: re your 1st comment - I don't like or recommend k-means, anyway. It's simple, but that's all it has going for it. Re your 2nd comment - please note I wrote *usually*. I was going to add a disclaimer that of course there are clustering algorithms that do not simply work on distance matrices, but elected to keep my answer simple. I'd be happy to see an answer that goes into deeper details.

Comment: Hi Stephan, can you elaborate on the distance part a bit please? I am fairly new to this.

Comment: I added a paragraph on distances and similarities. Hope it helps.

Comment: You can't use k-means here. Because you can't compute the *mean*. K-means doesn't use distances between two points. It uses *center-to-point*. Also don't put other distances into k-means, because **k-means may fail converging**. The *mean* optimizes squared deviations, not arbitrary distances. I've repeatedly posted counterexamples here, e.g. for absolute pearson correlation.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, **use search**. This has been answered in detail repeated, so I'm not going to copy and paste it all here.

- [Appropriate cluster method?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49887/appropriate-cluster-method)

If you have mixed type data, the first thing to do is **understand how to measure similarity**. If you don't understand your data, no clustering algorithm will.

- [Distance function for categories in K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31308/distance-function-for-categories-in-k-means)

k-means only works for *linear numerical data*. It needs to compute centers (the "means" in "k-means"). If you cannot compute a center that *minimizes* your distance, k-means will fail to converge. You have to use other algorithms such as hierarchical clustering, PAM, DBSCAN or CLARA, or ... hundreds of others. But first solve the *distance* problem, they all need a *reliable* distance measure.